# Checking for a DOM element that disappears quickly e.g. loading bar

Tags: google-chrome, dom, dom-events

Given that you have the class name of an element (e.g. loading bar) that disappears very quickly, how would one check if a certain event like clicking a button would prompt that element to appear/disappear? I'm trying to use Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in source tab of dev tools https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CoESC2XGZLg

Comment: I don't know which line is relevant. For example, if you click the share button on this post,  I can see under Dev Tools > Elements, which element is being affected. The DOM change I'm looking for on this site happens too quickly for me to monitor this way.

Comment: Start from the top and go line by line (F10), unless you can inspect the element and jump to where you need to be it's the only way, may be.